# R for loop to calculate wilcox.test

Tags: r, for-loop, data.table, empty-list

I am trying to write a code that would automatically calculate Wilcoxon test p-value for several comparisons.

Data used: 2 data sets with the same information representing two groups of participants completed the same 5 tasks which means that the each table contains 5 columns (tasks) and X rows with tasks scores.

```
data_17_18_G2  # first data set (in data.table format)
data_18_20_G2  # second data set (in data.table format)
```

Both data sets have identical names of column which are to be used in the W-test the next way:

```
wilcox.test(Group1Task1, Group2Task1, paired = F)
wilcox.test(Group1Task2, Group2Task2, paired = F)
```

and so on.
The inputs (e.g., Grou1Task1) are two vectors of task scores (the first one will be from data_17_18_G2 and the other one from data_18_20_G2

Desired output: a data table with a column of p-values
The problem I faced is that no matter how I manipulated the val1 and val2 empty objects, in the second and the third lines the right size "as.numeric(unlist(data_17_18_G2[, ..i]))" gives a correct output (a numeric vector) but it's left size "val1[i]" always returns only one value from the vector. That gave me the idea that the main problem appeared on the step of creating an empty vector, however, I wasn't able to solve it.

Empty objects:

```
result <- data.table(matrix(ncol=2))
val1 <- as.numeric() # here I also tried functions "numeric" and "vector" 
val2 <- as.numeric()
res <- vector(mode = "list", length = 7)
```

For loop

```
for (i in 1:5) {
  val1[i] <- as.numeric(unlist(data_17_18_G2[ , ..i]))  
  val2[i] <- as.numeric(unlist(data_18_20_G2[ , ..i]))
  res[i] <- wilcox.test(val1[i], val2[i], paired = F)
  result[i, 1] <- i
  result[i, 2] <- res$p.value
}
```

Output:

```
Error in `[<-.data.table`(`*tmp*`, i, 2, value = NULL) :
  When deleting columns, i should not be provided

1: В val1[i] <- as.numeric(unlist(data_17_18_G2[, ..i])) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
2: В val2[i] <- as.numeric(unlist(data_18_20_G2[, ..i])) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
3: В res[i] <- wilcox.test(val1[i], val2[i], paired = F) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Alternative: 
I changed the second and the third lines

```
for (i in 1:5) {
  val1[i] <- as.numeric(data_17_18_G2[ , ..i])
  val2[i] <- as.numeric(data_18_20_G2[ , ..i])
  res[i] <- wilcox.test(val1[i], val2[i], paired = F)
  result[i, 1] <- i
  result[i, 2] <- res$p.value
}
```

And got this

```
Error in as.numeric(data_17_18_G2[, ..i]) :
(list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

which means that the function wilcox.test cannot interpret this type of input.

How can I improve the code so that I get a data table of p-values?

Comment: Could you please post a sample of your data (using `dput()`)? It's hard to tell what's going on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There would appear to be some bugs in the code. I have rewritten the code using the cars dataset as a example.

```
## use the cars dataset as a example (change with appropriate data)
data(cars)

data_17_18_G2  <- as.data.table(cars)
data_18_20_G2  <- data_17_18_G2[,2:1]

## Fixed code

result <- data.table(matrix(as.numeric(), nrow=ncol(data_17_18_G2), ncol=2))
val1 <- as.numeric() 
val2 <- as.numeric()
res <- vector(mode = "list", length = 7)

for (i in 1:ncol(data_17_18_G2)) {
  val1 <- as.numeric(unlist(data_17_18_G2[ , ..i]))  
  val2 <- as.numeric(unlist(data_18_20_G2[ , ..i]))
  res[[i]] <- wilcox.test(val1, val2, paired = F)
  result[i, 1] <- as.numeric(i)
  result[i, 2] <- as.numeric(res[[i]]$p.value)
}
```

Hope this gives you the output you are after.

Comment: Thank you! Your solution helped me a lot. It still didn't like the framework for "result" so I changed it to data.frame `result <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 2))`, all the rest worked great!